# Flask Form 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to make a form do something in my flask web app (twitter clone) but whenever I add :

```
action={{ url_for('tweet') }}
```

to my form, it gives me a

> 500 Internal Server Error

and in the terminal is shows

> "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -

I've looked online for a solution but could not find anything that helped.
I'm only getting my form to return a simple string on screen. I'm also getting the error when I try to load the index page, not use the form.

Any ideas here on what I'm doing wrong? I'm following an online tutorial and am sure I've followed the instructions correctly.

Here is the relevant code:

***My html:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Fake Twitter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/css.css') }}">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/favicon.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
    <img id="logo" src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/logo.png') }}">

    <section>

        <div id="leftDiv">

            <!-- <button id="composeButton" type="button" onclick="tweetForm()">Compose Tweet</button> -->


            <form id="tweetForm" name="tweetForm" action="{{ url_for('tweet') }}" method="POST">

            <h1>Compose Tweet</h1>

                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Username</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="usernameField" name="username">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Tweet<br><i>(Max 140 chars)</i></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <textarea id="tweetContentField" name="tweetContent" size="140"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
                <button id="sendTweet">Send Tweet</button>
                </td></tr>
                </table>

            </form>

        </div>

        <div id="rightDiv">

            <div class="tweetDiv">

                <p class="user">@DarachRonayne</p>

                <p class="tweetContent">Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor amet, consectetur, adipisci velit. Neque poro quisquam est qui dolorem. Neque porrrro.</p>

                <p class="timestamp">Timestamp Here</p>

                <button class="deleteButton" type="button">Delete Tweet</button>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

</body>

<script src="{{ url_for('static',filename='js/js.js') }}"></script>

</html>
```

***My Python file:***

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/tweet', methods=['POST'])
def tweet():
    return 'TWEET TWEET!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

app.run(debug=True, port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: `action={{ url_for('tweet') }}` might raise a server error since you did not import it as `url_for()`. Use either `action={{ flask.url_for('tweet') }}` or `from flask import render_template, url_for` See [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for)

Comment: @albert It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`action={{ url_for('tweet') }}` might raise a server error since you did not import it as `url_for()`. Use either `action={{ flask.url_for('tweet') }}` or `from flask import render_template, url_for`.

See [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for).

<sup>comment made by [albert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3991125/albert)</sup>